# Flip the order of entries in the second column of the matrix

Tags: r

I'm using the programming language R. I have a 2x2 matrix, and I need to    flip the order of entries in the second column of the matrix. Here is the code for my matrix:

```
vector = c("Tom", "Smith", "Carl", "Gauss")

matrix = matrix(vector, nrow = 2)

matrix

Output:

 "Tom"   "Carl" 
 "Smith" "Gauss"
```

I'm trying to find a function in R that would flip the order of the second column like this:

```
 "Tom"   "Gauss" 
 "Smith" "Carl"
```

Comment: Is it only for specific cases? Or is this just a smaller example of a larger problem where you cannot hardcode actual names?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rev` function from the `base` package.

```r
vector = c("Tom", "Smith", "Carl", "Gauss")

matrix = matrix(vector, nrow = 2)

matrix[, 2] <- rev(matrix[, 2])

print(matrix)
#>      [,1]    [,2]   
#> [1,] "Tom"   "Gauss"
#> [2,] "Smith" "Carl"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming that you are working with 2*2 matrix similar to the one you have provided.

```
vector = c("Tom", "Smith", "Carl", "Gauss")

(matrix = matrix(vector, nrow = 2))
```

Instead of using a function, you can use the the indexes from the vector to flip the names within the matrix.

```
matrix[1,2]=vector[4]
matrix[2,2]=vector[3]

matrix

     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "Tom"   "Gauss"
[2,] "Smith" "Carl"
```